# iOS Loading an Image from a URL

Tags: ios, uiimage

I am experiencing some issues when I load a UIImage from a URL into a UIImageView on the iPhone.  When I generate the NSURL (with the URL in the argument of NSURL's URLWithString method) using properties of an object, the image is not retrieved at all, however if I hardcode the same URL, the image is retrieved and displayed as expected.
The [item valueForKey:@"pictureLocation"]; part below seems to be what is causing the problem because even when two hardcoded strings are concatenated, the NSURl is generated with no issues.

```
NSString * imagePath = @"http://localhost:3000";
NSString * specificPath = (NSString *)[item valueForKey:@"pictureLocation"] ;   
//concatenate the strings to get a fully formed URL
NSString * finalPath = [imagePath stringByAppendingString:specificPath];    

UIImage *img = [[UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString:finalPath]]] retain];
```

Essentially, when I NSLog the finalPath and instead hardcode that URL into the program, I get the expected result.

Why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0):

How is the `NSString` returned by `valueForKey:` formed?  Is it something like "image.png", or is it "/image.png"?  If it's the former, you'll want to use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:` instead of `stringByAppendingString:`.

Comment: Thanks for your response...
the URL formed from this code is correct and displays the image when input into a browser...

Comment: What's the URL string look like after the string has been concatenated?

Comment: it's fully formed and resolves correctly in a browser:
http://localhost:3000/pictures/picture.jpg

Comment: So it it `@"localhost:3000..."`, or is it `@"http://localhost:3000..."`?  Your initial question says the latter, but make sure, because NSURL won't work without the http://.  Another thing you could test is to see if it's storing the port correctly--try the `port` method, which returns an `NSNumber`.

Comment: My comment should have had http:// on the latter string--forgot to escape the URL.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
My apologies, the localhost URL should have http:// in front of it..
really what I am doing is hardcoding "http://localhost:3000" and then appending a string retrieved from an XML page ("/pictures/picture.jpg") and passing the resulting string to NSURL....the concatenated string WORKS if i just pass it directly in to NSURL (=source of confusion).

Comment: Subview Controller's viewdidload method:
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
 imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
 NSString * imagePath = @"http://localhost:3000";
 NSString * specificPath = (NSString *)[item valueForKey:@"picture"] ; 
 NSString * url = [imagePath stringByAppendingString:specificPath]; 
 NSLog(@"url = ");
 NSLog(url);   //prints correct URL
 NSData* imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
 UIImage* image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
 [imageView setImage:image];
 [imageData release];
 [image release];
}

Comment: Try comparing the concatenated string with the hardcoded version (isEqualToString:), just to make sure they are exactly the same.  Also make sure the port is getting set properly in the NSURL object (port method).

Comment: weird! the two strings are not equal!
how do i fix this!?

Comment: hmm turns out there were some whitespace characters that came back from the XML string.  
I have them removed and the strings are equal but i am getting the same result.
Also:  NSString * port = [[nsurl port] stringValue];
 NSLog(@"urlport");
        NSLog(port);
is not printing anything

Comment: Strange.  Is the encoding for the concatenated string something different from UTF8?  Also, for easier NSLog use, you can do something like NSLog(@"%@", [url port]);  It's just like printf.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the UIWebView and load a html `<img />` inside it.
At least this is a nice workaround.

Check the code here http://blog.timeister.com/2009/07/18/iphone-show-online-image/

```
- (void)loadImage:(NSString*)url frame:(CGRect)frame {
NSString* textHTML = @"
<html><head>
<style type=\"text/css\">
body {
background-color: transparent;
color: white;
}
</style>
</head><body style=\"margin:0\">
<img  src=\"%@\"  width=\"%0.0f\" height=\"%0.0f\"></img>
</body></html>";

NSString* html = [NSString stringWithFormat:textHTML, url, frame.size.width, frame.size.height];

if(webView == nil) {
webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
[self.view addSubview:webView];
}

[webView loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];
}
```

---

Adrian

Comment: I will try this.
I am confused though because when I simply use the image's full URL directly in the [NSURL URLWithString] method, the image appears...

Comment: The fact it works with a hard-coded URL tells you the problem lies in the string creation.  I think you'll get the same result with this solution--you need to make sure the NSURL object created with the concatenated string isn't null.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is related to proper encoding.

try encoding the parameters properly by using following function :

```
encodedparams = [params stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

So in your case :

```
NSString * specificPath = (NSString *)[item valueForKey:@"pictureLocation"] ;
specificPath = [specificPath stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I think this will solve your problem.